# Unix - How to copy list of files from a remote machine

Tags: file, unix, copy

I have a list of files with no specific pattern on a unix machine.
I want to copy these files from that machine to my local machine.

For example, i have the list in a text file

***fileslist.txt***

> a.txt
>
> b.txt
>
> c.txt
>
> d.txt

Using this list, i want to copy from these files from the remote machine.

What is the best possible way? As far as i know scp supports only wild card.

Answer (score 0):

xargs is your friend.

```
cat files.txt | xargs scp user@remote:
```